# Problem assigning value obtained from [array objectAtIndex:]

Tags: objective-c, arrays

In my Piano class, I have a property (Keys is another custom class)

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) Keys *lastPlayed;
```

In one of my Piano methods, I set the value of lastPlayed using an object from an array of Key objects.

```
self.lastPlayed = [allKeys objectAtIndex:variable];
```

The above line of code causes the program to crash.

I've noticed that if I hardcode a specific Key object from the allKeys array, then it works fine. Like so:

```
self.lastPlayed = keyC;
```

Interestingly, it doesn't crash if I put the crashing code into a different method.

How can I prevent the crash?

EDIT:

I call this method in the Keys class, where my piano is the delegate

```
[delegate deliverTagwithNameTag:self.tag]
```

the piano then responds

```
- (void) deliverTagwithNameTag:(int)nameTag {

self.lastPlayed = [allKeys objectAtIndex:nameTag];

}
```

Comment: Please post the output of the crash log, and more code showing where these lines are in relation to your other code.

Comment: We're going to need more info for this one.  I'm thinking that it's probably a null pointer or index out of bounds exception.  But can't be sure without more info.  What type of error are you crashing with?

Comment: thats the problem, it's not showing one. it just crashes and says bad access when i call the method

Comment: Could you type 'bt' into gdb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably not getting a plain unexplained crash, you're probably raising an exception. You can watch the console to find out which exception you raised. Normally in this sort of situation it'll be something useful to tell you either that you're asking the array for an out-of-bounds value (which could happen if `variable` were collecting an incorrect value somehow), that the array itself is invalid (which could be a memory allocation problem) or that the thing returned can't be stored as `lastPlayed` (which would normally indicate you're doing something custom in the setter and getting an unexpected type of class).

So to prevent the crash, check your console and look for one of those problems.

Comment: This time it doesn't show me one for some reason.

It just shows the bad access thing when i try to call the method

Comment: Is that when you try to call the setter or when you try to call the array? If it's the former then probably someone has over-released whatever you put into the array, if it's the latter then probably someone has over-released the array.

Comment: its for this line [delegate deliverTagwithNameTag:self.tag]

I added more code to explain

Comment: You should try logging the value of `nameTag` and `[allKeys count]` immediately before the offending line. That'd give you some more information.